# What does "Ce gros homme point sot était rempli de qualités dont quelques-unes au moins étaient d'un roi" mean?

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm reading "French for reading" by Karl C. Sandberg and hit this paragraph :

> Louis XVI
>
> Par malheur, Louis XV mourut. Par malheur  encore Louis XVI lui
> succéda. Ce gros homme point sot était rempli de qualités dont
> quelques-unes au moins étaient d'un roi. Il était travailleur ,
> attentif, consciencieux, bien intentionné .  Il avait des
> connaissances, de la mémoire, du jugement.  Ayant eu la force de
> soustraire sa politique étrangère aux factions, il trouva l'homme
> qu'il fallait pour la réaliser , profita des leçon du règne précédent
> , reconstitua la marine et réussit à maintenir la paix sur le
> continent tout en prenant sur mer et aux colonies la revanche du traité de Paris .

What does "*Ce gros homme point sot était rempli de qualités dont quelques-unes au moins étaient d'un roi*" mean? Basically I'm lost on *point* (does it mean *point*?) and *au moins* (does it mean *at least*?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> point

means "not" in this case, point is a rare and old synonym of  "pas", with [slight differences](http://www.espacefrancais.com/difference-entre-pas-et-point/)

> au moins

indeed means at least.

This sentence could be translated :

> This fat man who was not stupid was full of qualities, some of whom were fit to (those of) a king